# Edit dataframe entries using groupby object --pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

Consider the following dataframe:

```
     index      count     signal
       1          1         1
       2          1        NAN
       3          1        NAN
       4          1        -1
       5          1        NAN
       6          2        NAN
       7          2        -1
       8          2        NAN
       9          3        NAN
       10         3        NAN
       11         3        NAN
       12         4        1
       13         4        NAN
       14         4        NAN
```

I need to 'ffill' the NANs in 'signal' and values with different 'count' value should not affect each other. such that I should get the following dataframe:

```
     index      count     signal
       1          1         1
       2          1         1
       3          1         1
       4          1        -1
       5          1        -1
       6          2        NAN
       7          2        -1
       8          2        -1
       9          3        NAN
       10         3        NAN
       11         3        NAN
       12         4        1
       13         4        1
       14         4        1
```

Right now I iterate through each data frame in group by object and fill NAN value and then copy to a new data frame:

```
new_table = np.array([]); 
for key, group in df.groupby('count'):
    group['signal'] = group['signal'].fillna(method='ffill')
    group1 = group.copy()
    if new_table.shape[0]==0:
        new_table = group1
    else:
        new_table = pd.concat([new_table,group1])
```

which kinda works, but really slow considering the data frame is large. I am wondering if there is any other method to do it with or without groupby methods. Thanks!

**EDITED:**

Thanks to Alexander and jwilner for providing alternative methods. However both methods are very slow for my big dataframe which has 800,000 rows of data.

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) method.

```
In [56]: df = pd.DataFrame({"count": [1] * 4 + [2] * 5 + [3] * 2 , "signal": [1] + [None] * 4 + [-1] + [None] * 5})

In [57]: df
Out[57]:
    count  signal
0       1       1
1       1     NaN
2       1     NaN
3       1     NaN
4       2     NaN
5       2      -1
6       2     NaN
7       2     NaN
8       2     NaN
9       3     NaN
10      3     NaN

[11 rows x 2 columns]

In [58]: def ffill_signal(df):
   ....:     df["signal"] = df["signal"].ffill()
   ....:     return df
   ....:

In [59]: df.groupby("count").apply(ffill_signal)
Out[59]:
    count  signal
0       1       1
1       1       1
2       1       1
3       1       1
4       2     NaN
5       2      -1
6       2      -1
7       2      -1
8       2      -1
9       3     NaN
10      3     NaN

[11 rows x 2 columns]
```

However, be aware that `groupby` reorders stuff. If the count column doesn't always stay the same or increase, but instead can have values repeated in it, `groupby` might be problematic. That is, given a `count` series like `[1, 1, 2, 2, 1]`, `groupby` will group like so: `[1, 1, 1], [2, 2]`, which could have possibly undesirable effects on your forward filling. If that were undesired, you'd have to create a new series to use with `groupby` that always stayed the same or increased according to changes in the count series -- probably using `pd.Series.diff` and `pd.Series.cumsum`

Answer (score 4):

I know it's very late, but I found a solution that is much faster than those proposed, namely to collect the updated dataframes in a list and do the concatenation only at the end. To take your example:

```
new_table = [] 
for key, group in df.groupby('count'):
    group['signal'] = group['signal'].fillna(method='ffill')
    group1 = group.copy()
    if new_table.shape[0]==0:
        new_table = [group1]
    else:
        new_table.append(group1)

new_table = pd.concat(new_table).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It inspired me to come up with a quick solution. But there should be a better way to transform the actual grouped dataframes in a groupby object. On a different note, I think the if-construct can be ignored and simple new_table.append(group1) should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to create a pivot table, forward fill values, and then map them back into the original DataFrame.

```
df2 = df.pivot(columns='count', values='signal', index='index').ffill()
df['signal'] = [df2.at[i, c] 
                for i, c in zip(df2.index, df['count'].tolist())]
>>> df
    count  index  signal
0       1      1       1
1       1      2       1
2       1      3       1
3       1      4      -1
4       1      5      -1
5       2      6     NaN
6       2      7      -1
7       2      8      -1
8       3      9     NaN
9       3     10     NaN
10      3     11     NaN
11      4     12       1
12      4     13       1
13      4     14       1
```

With 800k rows of data, the efficacy of this approach depends on how many unique values are in 'count'.

Compared to my prior answer:

```
%%timeit 
for c in df['count'].unique():
    df.loc[df['count'] == c, 'signal'] = df[df['count'] == c].ffill()

100 loops, best of 3: 4.1 ms per loop

%%timeit 
df2 = df.pivot(columns='count', values='signal', index='index').ffill()
df['signal'] = [df2.at[i, c] for i, c in zip(df2.index, df['count'].tolist())]

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.32 ms per loop
```

Lastly, you can simply use `groupby`, although it is slower than the previous method:

```
df.groupby('count').ffill()
Out[191]: 
    index  signal
0       1       1
1       2       1
2       3       1
3       4      -1
4       5      -1
5       6     NaN
6       7      -1
7       8      -1
8       9     NaN
9      10     NaN
10     11     NaN
11     12       1
12     13       1
13     14       1

%%timeit
df.groupby('count').ffill()

100 loops, best of 3: 3.55 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data has been pre-sorted on df['index'], try using `loc` instead:

```
for c in df['count'].unique():
    df.loc[df['count'] == c, 'signal'] = df[df['count'] == c].ffill()

>>> df
    index  count signal
0       1      1      1
1       2      1      1
2       3      1      1
3       4      1     -1
4       5      1     -1
5       6      2    NaN
6       7      2     -1
7       8      2     -1
8       9      3    NaN
9      10      3    NaN
10     11      3    NaN
11     12      4      1
12     13      4      1
13     14      4      1
```

Comment: Thank you, it is very slow though… I have 800,000 rows of data which takes forever.